# spring integration test cleanup for conflicting configuration contexts

Tags: java, spring, junit, spring-test

I'm working on an application where we use integration tests intensively since a core framework we are using operates on the database.

I have test classes using configuration context class such as this:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = ConfigA.class)
public A_Test(){ 

}
```

The majority of tests are using same context like above. We have over 200+ such tests. But recently we needed some additional configuration for some use cases as well, like this:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {ConfigA.class, ConfigB.class})
public B_Test(){ 

}
```

Problem is now when we execute all tests with maven, or IDE runners , loaded cache for ConfigA no longer works. Spring tries to recreate a context for ConfigA which fails because we have H2 DB already configured and Spring tries to create schemas, tables which fails to do so.

To overcome we started to use @DirtiesContext on all tests. Result is over 1H build time, which reduces the developer productivity significantly.

Question: is it possible to clear context for tests like `B_Test` only? @DirtiesContext(ClassMode=AFTER_CLASS) doesn't help because order of the tests are not guaranteed(and really we don't want to go that way). It fails when type of B_Test tests are last to run. Same for @DirtiesContext(ClassMode=BEFORE_CLASS) visa versa

Is it possible to simulate @DirtiesContext(ClassMode=AFTER_CLASS)  and @DirtiesContext(ClassMode=BEFORE_CLASS) at the same time on a bunch of tests?

Or is there any other way to solve in general this problem?

What we tried so far:

1. Junit Suites : didn't help anything with spring context
2. ContextHierarchies : didn't help with the case that B_Type tests also dirties the context
3. Test Ordering: well nobody is really happy about refactoring all the tests to make it work magically

Comment: Could you please add your connection string?

Answer (score 2):

How about using both @DirtiesContext(ClassMode=AFTER_CLASS) and @DirtiesContext(MethodMode=BEFORE_METHOD)?

When you do that, Spring will reload context ConfigA.class and ConfigB.class just before invoking test methods annotated with @DirtiesContext(MethodMode=BEFORE_METHOD).
And then, after all tests of B_Test finished, Spring shutdowns the contexts (and next test class with SpringJUnit4ClassRunner will load its context).

Comment: hmm, we still have spring version 4.1.9 never was able to try before_claass actually. I will try it

Answer (score 0):

This is essentially a duplicate of [Make Spring Boot Recreate Test Databases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28694536/make-spring-boot-recreate-test-databases).

In summary, you likely only need to ensure that you are using unique names for each embedded database that is created using your `ConfigA` class.

Please read my comments here for details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28867247/388980

Also, see the comments in [SPR-8849](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-8849) for further details.

Regards,

Sam (*author of the Spring TestContext Framework*)

Comment: i checked that but I believe essential problem in my case is this: `@ContextConfiguration(classes = {ConfigA.class, ConfigB.class})` for this , Spring doesn't reuse already cached ConfigA.class from previous tests with `@ContextConfiguration(classes = ConfigA.class)` . I presume to identify the cache Spring uses `classes` as a whole as key. Would it not be possible to separately identify the caches?